# Error encountered Adding and Deleting Apps from App Bundle in ITC

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I am trying to add and remove apps from an App Bundle. If I look at the app bundle when it is live, I do not see an `Edit` button (instead there's an `Arrange` button). **If I remove the App Bundle from sale (uncheck "cleared for sale"), I get an `edit` button.** Then, I add an app to the bundle (or remove an app from the bundle), but on save, message is:

> Error encountered saving or updating bundle: Attempt to add or remove apps from a bundle that does not allow editing.

[image]

**How can I add or remove apps from an app bundle in Tunes Connect?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Email with iTunesConnect Support (2016-11-05):

> To answer your question, no you can not change the app bundle once it has been approved.  In order to change it, you would basically need to create a new app bundle to submit for review.  Here is a link that has some frequently asked questions regarding bundles:
>
> https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/App%20Bundles_Managing%20Bundles